# Enable service watching while the data changes between controller and directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I'm trying to toggle a class by setting a Boolean value with `ng-class`. Now while using a custom directive while clicking outside of my focusing element needs to change the Boolean to false.

```
app.factory('collapsed', function($rootScope){
    var scope = $rootScope.$new(true);
    scope.isCollapsed = true
    return scope;
})
app.controller('optSideNav', optSideNav);
function optSideNav(collapsed) {
    var self = this;
    this.isCollapsed = collapsed.isCollapsed;
}
app.directive('offFocusing', ['$document', 'collapsed', function ($document, collapsed) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            console.log(element)
            function elementClick(e) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                scope.isCollapsed = collapsed.isCollapsed;
            }
            element.on('click', elementClick);
            // remove event handlers when directive is destroyed
            scope.$on('$destroy', function () {
                element.off('click', elementClick);
            });
        }
    };
}]);


<!--controller area --> 
    <navng-class="sideNav.isCollapsed ? 'opt-sideNav' : 'opt-sideNavXl'" ng-controller="optSideNav as sideNav" ng-model="sideNav.isCollapsed">
   <a ng-click="sideNav.isCollapsed = !sideNav.isCollapsed""><i class="material-icons md-16">menu</i></a>
</nav>
<!--directive area-->
 <section class="opt-appArea" flex layout="column" off-focusing>
</section>
```

How do I asynchronously obtain the value changes while click element to controller?